# Configure XSLT stylesheet in SSRS Report Subscription?

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to apply a stylesheet, or even just design a SSRS with an XML output format. Can I do this transformation or design from the reporting admin tool on the webserver? Ideally I'd like the data driven subscription to allow for an XSLT reference. Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Rendering Extensions is looking interesting.

Answer (score 1):

yes have a look at the the following url which applies and xslt to the report

```
http://localhost/reportserver?/AdventureWorks%20Sample%20Reports/Product+Catalog&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=XML&rc:OmitSchema=True&rc:FileExtension=txt&rc:XSLT=ProductModels.xsl
```

More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159716(v=sql.90).aspx